# the difference between opencv and skimage while reading PNG files

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, scikit-image

While reading the `PNG` image files, I tested the input process using both `opencv` and `skimage`, and found that the shape of the input image are different. What causes these differences, why `skimage` generate four channels for `PNG` file?

Here is the code segment

```
from skimage.io import imread
image = imread("C:\\Desktop\\test1.png")
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("C:\\Desktop\\test1.png")
print("skimage shape: ",image.shape)
print("cv2 shape: ",img.shape)
```

The output are

```
skimage shape:  (247, 497, 4)
cv2 shape:  (247, 497, 3)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OpenCV's `imread()` discards alpha channel (4th channel in BGRA) by default. If you want to keep it, you need to use [`IMREAD_UNCHANGED`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga61d9b0126a3e57d9277ac48327799c80) flag:

> **IMREAD_UNCHANGED** Python: **cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED**
>
> If set, return the loaded image as is (with alpha channel, otherwise it gets cropped).

[skimage's `imread()`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html#skimage.io.imread) does not have this behavior. Alpha channel is included, if it exists:

> The different color bands/channels are stored in the third dimension, such that a gray-image is MxN, an RGB-image MxNx3 and an RGBA-image MxNx4.

As noted in comments, with default options OpenCV's `imread()` always returns 3 channel images with BGR color order (see `IMREAD_COLOR`). skimage's `imread()` uses RGB(A) order for color images and can return a single channel ndarray for grayscale images.

Comment: could be nice to mention, that opencv imread by default always provides a 3 channel 8 bit image, even if file is single channel or 16 bit.

Comment: Note also that the order of the color bands are swapped between these packages.